# Installed new DDR3 RAM DIMM, BIOS shows the RAM, but Windows is stuck at the boot logo

Tags: windows-7, memory, upgrade, ddr3

After installing the new RAM, BIOS registered 4096MB of RAM, but when trying to boot Windows, the Windows logo appears, then the PC reboot as soon as the loading animation starts, sometimes with a BSOD. If I  reinstall the old RAM, it works as expected, booting Windows successfully:

- **Motherboard:** Asrock H55M-LE 
   *2x DDR3 RAM slots with dual-channel 2600MHz and RAM overclocking support*
- **CPU:** Intel Core i3 3.06GHz x64 (Clarkdale)
- **RAM:** PC3-12800U-11

  - **New:** SK Hynix DDR3 4GB 1Rx8 (HMT451U6BFR8C-PBN0AA)
  - **Old:** Kingston DDR3 2GB (KVR 1333D3S8N9/2G-SP)

I've tried:

- Reinstalling Windows 7, but after loading Windows' files, installer does not move further than the starting logo, then reboots
- A memory test within Windows setup, but it's stuck at 0%
- Changing the RAM slots, but same result

When using both RAM DIMMs at once, BIOS displays `ENTERING SETUP` and `DUAL CHANNEL MEMORY MODE`, but does not load further than that.

How do I figure out what the issue is?

Comment: Try to run memtest86 and see if there are any errors

Comment: By the way what do you thinking about this? Faluty ram? Or compatible error?

Comment: At this point I don't know, memtest can shed some light on this

Comment: @gronostaj I tried memtest86 but it does not gives anything. I mean it does not starts. Only black screen.

Comment: Is your BIOS the latest version? If not, try to update it on the old stick.

Comment: It is AMI LEAGAL BIOS P1.00, How can i know whether it suppprts UEFI?

Comment: Most Probably a faulty Module. Is it a new DIMM? Than check for the issue in a second PC or RMA.

Comment: It most likely does support UEFI, but I don't see how that's related. Most recent BIOS version for H55M-LE is 1.80: https://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/H55M-LE/#BIOS (I couldn't find HM55M-LE, is that a typo?)

Comment: Sorry, typing mistake, you were right. It is H55M - LE.

Comment: You've edited the question, is the problem still not solved? Have you tried to update BIOS as I suggested?

Comment: @infinitecode Are you 100% certain the board supports that specific DDR3 DIMM type, as it could only be one of four things: **(1)** Incompatible DDR3 DIMM type; **(2)** A bad/damaged DIMM; **(3)** Damaged RAM slot(s); **(4)** Contamination, such as dust, on the DIMM terminals or within the RAM slots on the board. The fact the old DIMM still works if swapped back in rules out numbers 3 and 4 (try cleaning new DIIMM's terminals with Isopropyl alcohol), and I would recommend starting with determining whether that specific DDR3 DIMM type is compatible with the board, and if it is, it's a bad DIMM.

Comment: @JW0914 Yes, as mentioned in the official website. [link](https://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/H55M-LE/) .  Ram slots are working. Just because I tested them with my working ram. Though I'm not an expert, is there any thing to consider other than being the ram DDR3 and board supporting the speed?

Comment: @infinitecode The new RAM is an ECC [Error Correcting Code] SDRAM module and the motherboard doesn't support ECC RAM _(it's an incompatible RAM DIMM)_. Only certain motherboards, usually server boards, support ECC, and the two main features to be aware of are non-ECC/ECC and unbuffered/buffered RAM as neither formers are compatible with either's latter _(e.g. boards will specify whether they support ECC and whether the RAM needs to be buffered or unbuffered; if an incompatible DIMM is installed, the machine will do precisely what you're experiencing)_